# Retrieve a hiddenfield value through javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am using the following javascript to retrieve a value of a asp hidenfield.

```
var pagemode 
function setValue() {
pagemode= document.getElementById('<%#litTest.ClientID%>').value;
}

function Item_load(sender, eventArgs) {
 window.location.href = "Request.aspx?Request_ID=" + eventArgs.get_item().getMember('Request_ID').get_value() + "&ListType=" + pagemode;
}
```

The value to the hiddenfield is loaded in page load in code behind. I need to pass the value as a querystring and it comes as undefined.

I would really appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: Where is javascript placed on the page? Are you using a masterpage, and is the javascript placed in placeholder in the child page? It might be that the javascript is being executed before the hidden field is rendered in the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you don't get a reference to your hiddenfield? Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var litTestID = '<%= litTest.ClientID %>';

  function setValue() {
    var pagemode = $(litTestID).value;
    // ...
  }
</script>
```

Otherwise use the javascript debugger to inspect the order of executino and the variable values.

Comment: the value comes as undefined?